# require.js with angular and jquery cause script error

Tags: requirejs

Good day. I am beginner at require.js.

I have next scripts and css's in my html (style.css and script.js located at the same folder, where html is):

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.27/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.27/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I am adding require.js as a first script:

```
<script data-main="main" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.1/require.js"></script>
```

and adding main.js, writing there:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl:"",
    paths: {            
    "jquery":"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js",
        "bootstrap":"http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    (etc etc)    
    }
});

define(["jquery"], function() {

});

define(["bootstrap"], function() {

});
etc
```

I got

```
Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: main
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

what I have to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From RequireJS Documentation:

```js
requirejs.config({
    //By default load any module IDs from js/lib
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    //except, if the module ID starts with "app",
    //load it from the js/app directory. paths
    //config is relative to the baseUrl, and
    //**never includes a ".js" extension since
    //the paths config could be for a directory**.
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
```

Paths are not supposed to end with ".js". Your code should work fine by removing the ".js" from your paths.